# Purpose of an input resistor to a signal transformer?

Tags: resistors, transformer, circuit-design

[Jensen's datasheet for their "Direct Box" transformer](http://www.jensen-transformers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/jt-db-e.pdf) has this recommended schematic for general use:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f154Z5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(shields not shown because CircuitLab doesn't have a shielded transformer symbol)

I'm not sure that I fully understand R1.  They send me a pack of 6.8k 1/4-watt leaded resistors with every order - one for each transformer - and while I use them as recommended, I can't seem to convince myself that they're actually needed.  Especially when [their app notes](http://www.jensen-transformers.com/schematics/) are all over the map concerning its value and even its presence.

I guess I can see some benefit to providing a minimum impedance that is higher than the primary winding resistance, but is there actually another purpose for R1?

Comment: It's a current limiter. The source impedance typically is >100kΩ, so the resistor doesn't matter for the intended purpose. But accidentally connect DC to the input and your transformer is busted without that resistor.

Comment: @Janka Maybe so, but with a primary winding resistance of 4.6k in a ~1 inch x ~1 inch metal can with a typical 15-0-15V power supply for the source, I would think it could take that.  (30VDC into 4.6kOhms = ~200mW)  But I guess it's good insurance anyway.  And now that I think about it that way, the potting material might be a decent thermal insulator too.  I was looking for more of a theoretical poor response that corrects nicely with a resistor but is hard to design away internally.  Nothing like that?